# C# Invalid variance error when having an out method parameter

Tags: c#, generics, c#-7.2, invariance

I have looked at similar questions, though my case seems to be different.

For this code:

```
public interface MyInterface<out T> {
  bool TrySomething(out T val);
}
```

I get this error on C# 7.2:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'MyInterface.TrySomething(out T)'. 'T' is covariant.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I am not supplying the `T` value here, I am getting it out (i.e. reading, hence the `out` method parameter modifier in `TrySomething`. So, why doesn't it compile?

Comment: No, a parameter goes _into_ the method, whether it's marked `out` or not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I did not see the question you mentioned.

Comment: No problem, hope it clears things up!